# Use jq to parse key path for each each leaf

Tags: json, jq

(I’m not sure the technical terms to use but can update the question if someone can clarify the terminology I’m lacking for what I'm trying to do. It might help someone find this answer in the future.)

Given the input JSON, how would I use jq to produce the expected output?

Input:

```
{
    "items": {
        "item1": {
            "part1": {
                "a": {
                    "key1": "value",
                    "key2": "value"
                },
                "b": {
                    "key1": "value",
                    "key2": "value"
                }
            },
            "part2": {
                "c": {
                    "key1": "value",
                    "key2": "value"
                },
                "d": {
                    "key1": "value",
                    "key2": "value"
                }
            }
        },
        "item2": {
            "part3": {
                "e": {
                    "key1": "value",
                    "key2": "value"
                },
                "f": {
                    "key1": "value",
                    "key2": "value"
                }
            },
            "part4": {
                "g": {
                    "key1": "value",
                    "key2": "value"
                },
                "h": {
                    "key1": "value",
                    "key2": "value"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "item1": [
        "part1.a",
        "part1.b",
        "part2.c",
        "part2.d"
    ]
    "item2": [
        "part3.e",
        "part3.f"
        "part4.g",
        "part4.h"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.items | map_values([path(.[][]) | join(".")])
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/8UchU9XCXp)</sup>

Each output path will contain as many path components as the number of `[]`s in the `.[][]` part; in other words, if you change `.[][]` to `.[][][]`, for example, you'll see `part1.a.key1`, `part1.a.key2`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```
# Output: a stream
def keyKey:
  keys_unsorted[] as $k | $k + "." + (.[$k] | keys_unsorted[]);

.items | map_values([keyKey])
```

Answer (score 0):

Some aspects are underspecified. For instance, you don't specify how deep the aggregation should go for the array items. Is it always two levels deep, or is it the whole tree but the last level?

Here's one way how you would go two levels deep with the keys sorted alphabetically:

```sh
jq '.items | .[] |= [keys[] as $k | $k + "." + (.[$k] | keys[])]'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/wKtYzSmsr0)

Here's another way how to go down until the second-to-last level:

```sh
jq '.items | .[] |= ([path(.. | scalars)[:-1] | join(".")] | unique)'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/tDvRm_ZSp5)

Output:

```json
{
  "item1": [
    "part1.a",
    "part1.b",
    "part2.c",
    "part2.d"
  ],
  "item2": [
    "part3.e",
    "part3.f",
    "part4.g",
    "part4.h"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the unique sequence of `jq` paths of 'keys' to each and every leaf
is returned from `json2jqpath.jq`

```
 json2jqpath.jq dat.json 
.
.items
.items|.item1
.items|.item1|.part1
.items|.item1|.part1|.a
.items|.item1|.part1|.a|.key1
.items|.item1|.part1|.a|.key2
.items|.item1|.part1|.b
.items|.item1|.part1|.b|.key1
.items|.item1|.part1|.b|.key2
.items|.item1|.part2
.items|.item1|.part2|.c
.items|.item1|.part2|.c|.key1
.items|.item1|.part2|.c|.key2
.items|.item1|.part2|.d
.items|.item1|.part2|.d|.key1
.items|.item1|.part2|.d|.key2
.items|.item2
.items|.item2|.part3
.items|.item2|.part3|.e
.items|.item2|.part3|.e|.key1
.items|.item2|.part3|.e|.key2
.items|.item2|.part3|.f
.items|.item2|.part3|.f|.key1
.items|.item2|.part3|.f|.key2
.items|.item2|.part4
.items|.item2|.part4|.g
.items|.item2|.part4|.g|.key1
.items|.item2|.part4|.g|.key2
.items|.item2|.part4|.h
.items|.item2|.part4|.h|.key1
.items|.item2|.part4|.h|.key2
```

It is not the output you asked for but as another noted, your question may be somewhat under specified. starting from a preprocessed structure such as this has the advantage of reducing *every* json file to its set of paths to start fiddling with.

[json2jqpath](https://github.com/TomConlin/json_to_paths)